# ideals in the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field and $\mathfrak{a}\subset \mathcal{O_K}$  an ideal . If $\beta \in \mathfrak{a}$, is the conjugate $\beta'$ also in $\mathfrak{a}$? I know it is true if $\mathfrak{a}=\mathcal{O_K}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(i)$, so that $\mathcal{O_K}=\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Let $\mathfrak{a}=(2+i)$, the ideal generated by $2+i$.

Then $\overline{2+i}=2-i\notin\mathfrak{a}$.